# how to use FontAwesome5 icons with same name in react native

Tags: react-native

how to use both circle in react native vector icons.

```
<i class="fas fa-circle"></i> solid circle.

<i class="far fa-circle"></i> regular circle.
```

[FontAwesome5Icons image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfANn.png)

```
import FontAwesome5Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';

Solid Circle<FontAwesome5Icon name="?" color={"#a65347"} size={20} solid />
Regular Circle<FontAwesome5Icon name="?" color={"#a65347"} size={20} solid />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please visit react-native-vector-icons [directory](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/) that is include all name and fonts that react-native-vector-icons implements them.

Use `circle` as name for solid circle and no icon for the regular one in FontAwesome5.

But you can use FontAwesome and use `circle-o` and `circle` for both of regular circle and solid circle.

you can import both of them like this:

```
import {default as FontAwesome5} from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import {default as FontAwesome} from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-native-vector-icons then the icon names must be used as mentioned in their [icon directory](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/)

In your case the names are **circle**, **circle-o** or **circle-thin** in FontAwesome section (picked up from [react-native-vector-icons directory](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/)).

You can do the following to implement:

```
import FontAwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

Solid Circle<FontAwesomeIcon name="circle" color={"#a65347"} size={20} />
Regular Circle<FontAwesomeIcon name="circle-o" color={"#a65347"} size={20} />
```